# LinearLayout component size. How does weight influence on size

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I need to set equal sizes to the buttons on the screen. These buttons have different content (different length). I want it to look like in line number 3 on picture

[image]

I tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="B" />
```

But i got two little buttons of different size in the center of the screen. What is wrong?
Please, give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width param in the LinearLayout section to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `android:weightsum=10` to `LinearLayout` and divide your portions to may be 2,4,4. You can also adjust them by percentages (20%, 40%, 40%) to have a feel while constructing them in your Graphics.xml by using `Fast View` (the little square in the bottom-left of eclipse)->`Other`->`Properties` and enter the values while developing.

Comment: Thank you it works, but only if i add  in the LinearLayout 
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
like rahul wrote

Comment: Nice. As a user if you find the answer fully helpful you should accept by tick check or upvote if partially helpful.